# Drupal Views overflow

Tags: drupal, view

I have a Drupal 7 / Views question...
I have a site with some data reports displaying in various graphs/ gauges etc. I also have a "Data" page that shows all of the data used so the user can look through it and/or even download it. My problem stems from the views table overflows past the screen on the right with data. This in itself is not a big issue, but I was wondering if there was a way to contain the view inside a fixed size box/container that is scrollable. Much like a text box.

Again, not that it would help the functionality but sure would make it look nice and clean.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll probably get better help at http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use css to confine the views data in a scrollable div. Please have a look at nodes on http://drupaldeveloper.in